# Inability to Log into MetaMask

Tags: metamask

I had a MetaMask account with password. 
Had used password to connect to DDex exchange for Ethereum connectivity, transactions, and token balance checks. 
Recently, I deactivated MetaMask from one of my browsers, and can no longer log into MetaMask with password/ account. Why, and what way out?

Comment: Use the mnemonic phrase

Answer (score 2):

The password associated with your Metamask login is only a local password which actually protects the more important 12 word seed.

When you first generate a Metamask account, you should have been clearly prompted to save this 12 word seed which is truly the way to access your account.

[image]

When you go on a new computer, you are able to set any password you want to protect this seed, but your seed must remain the same to access the same Metamask account.